# How does one include the candleshape.def mentioned in shapepar?

Tags: shapepar

In the [documentation for `shapepar`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/shapepar/shapepar.pdf) a number of def files are mentioned, for example [`candleshape.def`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/shapepar/candleshape.def) but there is no example of how to use them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{shapepar}
\input{candleshape.def}

\begin{document}

\shapepar{\candle}
one two three four five six seven eight nine ten
one two three four five six seven eight nine ten
one two three four five six seven eight nine ten
one two three four five six seven eight nine ten
one two three four five six seven eight nine ten
one two three four five six seven eight nine ten


\end{document}
```